# function in the function's parameter

Tags: google-chrome-extension

the function is in function's parameter,for example

```
 function getAcceptLanguages() {
        chrome.i18n.getAcceptLanguages(function(languageList) {
          var languages = languageList.join(",");
          setChildTextNode('languageSpan',
              chrome.i18n.getMessage("chrome_accept_languages", languages));
        })
      }
```

the function is " chrome.i18n.getAcceptLanguages()" 
the function in function's parameter is :function(languageList) {...}

i really dont get it....how to send data to the  languageList.
hope someone can answer for me

Answer (score 1):

[chrome.i18n.getAcceptLanguages](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/i18n.html#method-getAcceptLanguages) is a async operation, so it need a callback function to return the languageList result. The browser will find the accept languages, then call the callback function with the result languageList as the parameter. So that you can get the result in the callback function.

Comment: so result will send to languageList.ah?
i have learned javascript,java,C,vb....
never saw this kind of code....
but this is good to different the parameters,which is really parameter or just getting result?
isnt?

Comment: Yes, `languageList` is the result of `chrome.i18n.getAcceptLanguages`. You can imagine that the callback function is called with the languageList result in the `getAcceptLanguages` implementation. Because it is an async call which cannot return the result immediately, so it is the only way to return the result to you.